# The Hardy space is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> The Hardy space $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is defined to be the space of all functions $f$ >holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ with the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_H$
>
> $\lVert f \rVert_H^2=\sup_{0<r<1}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta$
>
> is finite.
>
> Show that $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is a Hilbert space.

I have shown that if $f(z)=\sum_n c_nz^n$, then $\lVert f \rVert_H^2=2\pi \sum_n|c_n|^2$. How does this imply $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is a Hilbert space? What is the inner product induced by the norm?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Formula

Comment: So $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. If you know that $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a Hilbert space, then you know that $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: How you concluded that $||f||^2_H=2π\sum|c_n|^2 $ because when we substitute $f(z) $ in the norm defintion with it's taylor series, the square of modulus will contain the summation  how can we get it out to get this?@userHasNoNumber

Comment: Can any one help me @DisintegrationByParts

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inner product: $(f|g)=\sup_{0<r<1}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta}) \overline{g(re^{i\theta})}d\theta$

Comment: How do you come up with this inner product?

Comment: I think you want $\lim$ instead of $\sup$, though the norm can be defined with $\sup$.

Comment: This is wrong, it makes no sense to take the sup of complex numbers.

Comment: To show that a space is Hilbert it is not enough to find an inner product but you also have to show that the space is complete with respect to the norm induced by the inner product

Answer (score 2):

Try using this fact (called the *polarization identity*):

> A *Banach space* $\mathcal{B}$ with *norm* $\parallel \ .\parallel$ is a *Hilbert space* iff  $$\forall f,g \in \mathcal{B}, \ \ \ \ \parallel f+g\ \parallel +\parallel f-g \ \parallel = 2\left(\parallel f \ \parallel +\parallel g \ \parallel \right)$$ 
>   with $\langle f,g\rangle = \dfrac{1}{4} \left(\left(\parallel f+g \parallel - \parallel f-g \parallel \right) + i \left( \parallel f + ig \parallel - \parallel f - ig \parallel \right)  \right)$

In fact, letting $f(z) = \sum_{n}{a_n z^n}$, and $g(z) = \sum_{n}{b_n z^n}$, we have, $$|a_n + b_n|^2+|a_n - b_n|^2 = 2(|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2) \ \ \ \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$, (check! [$a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$]) and because all the terms in all the series are positive, we can write,  $$\parallel f+g\ \parallel +\parallel f-g \ \parallel = 2\pi \left(\sum_{n}{|a_n + b_n|^2}+ \sum_{n}{|a_n - b_n|^2}\right) = 2 \pi \left(2\left(\sum_{n}{|a_n|^2}+\sum_{n}{|b_n|^2}\right) \right) = 2\left(\parallel f \ \parallel +\parallel g \ \parallel \right)$$
Now you can try proving that the inner product you thus obtain is the same as the one @Fred has described!  In fact, check that $$\langle f,g \rangle = 2\pi \sum_{n}{a_n \overline{b_n}}$$
[Note that, even when you encounter a *Banach space* which you don't know the *inner product* formula for, you can thus check if it is a *Hilbert space* and describe an *inner product*.]

To show completeness, do the following:

- Let $\{f_n\}$ be *Cauchy* in $\mathbb{H}^2$.Say, $f_n(z) =
     \sum_{i}{a_{n,i} z^i}$. Using your formula for $\parallel .
     \parallel_{\mathbb{H}^2}$, $\{s_n\}:s_n = \{a_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$
  is *Cauchy* in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.
- $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ is complete. $$\Rightarrow \ \ \ \exists \{a_i\} \in l^2(\mathbb{N}), \ \ \ \{a_{n,i}\} \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{l^2(\mathbb{N})} \{a_i\}$$
- Define, $f(z) : = \sum_{i}{a_{i} z^i}$. Again, using your formula for $\parallel . \parallel_{\mathbb{H}^2}$, show that, $$f_{n} \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{\mathbb{H}^2} f$$

This finishes the proof.

Comment: I think the hard part will be proving completeness, that is that it is a Banach space.

Comment: The post seemed to be asking for the inner product and how to find it, that's why I restricted my answer. But as @DisintegratingByParts has pointed out - $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ is isomometric to $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{N})$, with $f \mapsto \{a_n\}_{n =1}^{\infty}$. 

I think we can just show that convergence of the corresponding sequence in $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{N})$ is equivalent to convergence in $H^2(\mathbb{D})$.